# Differences between building from git clone and downloaded zip

Tags: make, autoreconf, ubuntu

I'm trying to build the [xcb-util-xrm](https://github.com/Airblader/xcb-util-xrm) library manually. I found two links with build instructions one from the [issue tracker](https://github.com/Airblader/i3/issues/82) of `i3gaps` and one from this bug report [here](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39019).

The instructions in the first link are from 2016, in summary

```
git clone https://github.com/Airblader/xcb-util-xrm
cd xcb-util-xrm
git submodule update --init
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
```

Instructions in the second link are from 2013:

> 1) Add LT_INIT to configure.ac
>
> 2) Make autogen.sh do "rm -rf m4; git submodule update --init"

My question is, how can I build this library under ubuntu 16.04.1 if I only downloaded and extracted the zip file from [git hub](https://github.com/Airblader/xcb-util-xrm)?

What I did so far, I added `LT_INIT` to `configure.ac`. Then I ran the following command twice, one time with prefix option and once without. Both times I end up with the same result:

```
$ ./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal -I m4
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: running: libtoolize --copy
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Autoheader
autoreconf: running: automake --add-missing --copy --no-force
Makefile.am:35: error: 'pkgconfig_DATA' is used but 'pkgconfigdir' is undefined
Makefile.am:26: error: 'xcbinclude_HEADERS' is used but 'xcbincludedir' is undefined
autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1
```

My next investigation was to open `autogen.sh` (you can see the content of the file on git hub). This file contains two major commands and the first one `autoreconf -v --install || exit 1` returns the whole error stack above.

My problem is I don't know how to solve the error:

> Makefile.am:35: error: 'pkgconfig_DATA' is used but 'pkgconfigdir' is
>   undefined

I just opened `Makefile.am` and found the line 35 `pkgconfig_DATA = xcb-xrm.pc`. And I checked what's the default path for my `pkg-config`, but till now I have no clue how and where I can define `pkgconfigdir`.

```
$pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config
    /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2016 instructions worked for me, whether from a `git clone` or an archive, without bothering about `LT_INIT`. If you download the full release archive, [xcb-util-xrm-1.2.tar.gz](https://github.com/Airblader/xcb-util-xrm/releases/download/v1.2/xcb-util-xrm-1.2.tar.gz), you don't need to run `autogen.sh`, you can run `./configure` instead. If you download only a source archive, you won't have the contents of `m4`.

You do need to have `pkg-config` installed (this might explain the `Makefile.am` error you're getting) and `libxcb-util0-dev` (otherwise you'll get an error later).

Comment: When I have to use `--prefix=/usr` (the default is set to /usr/local/bin)? Both paths are owned by root. If I download [master.zip](https://github.com/Airblader/xcb-util-xrm/archive/master.zip), there for I have to run `git submodule update --init`?

Comment: You shouldn't use `--prefix=/usr` at all really, that's liable to mess things up with your package manager. The default `/usr/local` is appropriate. If you *do* want to change the prefix, you need to mention it any time you run `autogen.sh` and `configure`. The master archive doesn't contain a git repository so you can't run `git submodule`; if you want to use master you need to clone the repository.

Comment: But till now I don't understand, if I download and extract this zip file, then I run into the problems I described above when I start `./autogen.sh`. If I use the released tarball you mentioned everything worked fine.

Comment: The zip file doesn't contain everything you need. The two approaches are either to use the full release tarball, or a cloned repository; you can't build the software using only master.zip.